# Grails format date within input field

Tags: string, date, grails

I have tried formatting the date by changing the date format property in the i18n, also tried formatting it within my controller but can't get anything to work. I only need it formatted in this one spot. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Estimated EIU graduation    date" name="eiuGradDate" id="eiuGradDate"  value="${studentInfo.estimatedGradDate}">
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I have a Groovy String object with the following class: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl and I need to know how to convert it into either a Date or a regular String.

Comment: Provided `estimatedGradDate` is an actual `Date` class you could just do `value="${studentInfo.estimatedGradDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy')}"`

Comment: Its class is showing as this, class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, and I have no idea what that is?

Comment: That's a Groovy String.

Comment: Is there a way to turn that into a Date?

Answer (score 0):

You could use taglibs in order to do whatever you want whit this "value", in your case, parse some string to Date.

Here's some documentation:

[TagLib Doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#taglibs)

[Usage](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tag%20Libraries/Usage.html)

Regards.